# Random Memory location in rails form app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create form in rails and in one of attributes placeholder i am getting like some placeholder value `#<Arel::SelectManager:0x007f7c743abb58>`.

The placeholder "Project" in that attribute seem to be visible only when such text is removed manually.

Is this some kind of bug or any syntax mistake?

Below is the code where i am seeing error.

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :Project %>
  <%= f.text_field :project, placeholder: "Project" %>
  <button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add More Record</button>
</p>
```

Comment: "where i am seeing error" - what error?

Comment: what is the value of `project` of this object?

Comment: Why do you think it's placeholder value and not an actual value of the text field? (this explains why you see placeholder only when you remove this value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `project` variable you are passing to form `text_field` is an object not `text` or `string`.

suppose you have `name` attribute in project Model, so do something like.

```
<%= f.text_field :project.name, placeholder: "Project" %>
```

Make sure you are passing a `text` or `string` value to `f.text_field`